# Where does the System Information information come from on login?

Tags: login

I have a local server running Ubuntu 10.04 headlessly.
When I ssh to the server I get some core information about the system, such as

```
System load:  0.0                Processes:           XXX
Usage of /:   2.5% of 452.69GB   Users logged in:     0
Memory usage: 10%                IP address for lo:   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for eth0: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Temperature:  40 C
```

What is the command to get this information to print again? I tried looking in the rc.local and the bash.bashrc file to see how this was run, but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The command is

```
landscape-sysinfo
```

it is run from `/etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo` when you have installed the package landscape-common.

As of Ubuntu 12.04 (perhaps earlier), update-motd is run at login time by the PAM module pam_motd.so.  Originally, update-motd was a cron job.

---

`landscape-sysinfo` is a part of the package `landscape-common`, so if it's missing you can install it by the command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install landscape-common
```

Comment: slight mistake, it should be `/etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo` not `/etc/update-motd.d/run 50-landscape-sysinfo`

Comment: I've installed `landscape-common` but don't see the information when I log in again. Do I have to reboot the server?

Comment: Possibly useful additional info (referring to 14.04.3):

# `update-motd` appears to dynamically update `/var/run/motd.dynamic` and "interestingly" when you log-in you actually get the output from the previous run.
# `landscape-sysinfo` accepts some useful options (which can be set in `/etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo`), such as `--exclude-sysinfo-plugins=Network`