# Computer info when login in a tty virtual shell

Tags: command-line, system-info

When I'm logging into a tty virtual shell, I obtain system information of the computer, like system load, memory usage, hard disc space on / ...

I installed Ubuntu on two others computer but they don't show me system informations on tty virtual login, why? Which packet or script makes this information available?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answers, I found the name of the packet to install on this page: 
[Where does the System Information information come from on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7949/where-does-the-system-information-information-come-from-on-login)
It's the packet landscape-common which gives system informations to motd (thanks Darael). After I installed this packet, I can manually obtain system informations with typing: #landscape-sysinfo

Comment: You should paste the exact information you see on your screen. There are a range of way to show 'system information of the computer, like system load, memory usage, hard disc space on / ...', people do not know what program is producing them if you do not paste the output.

Answer (score 1):

What is output at login-time is generally controlled on *nix boxen (and, by extension, Ubuntu boxen) by the /etc/issue (controls what gets shown before the login: prompt) and /etc/motd (gets printed upon successful login) files.  On Ubuntu, the former is a single file the latter is autogenerated from /etc/motd.tail.  See also `man issue` (for /etc/issue - it will point you at `man agetty`, so look at that as well) and `man motd` and `man motd.tail`, which will give information on the motd files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see these info, you can put the following code in your `~/.profile`:

```
uname -a
w
df -hT /
```

I use similar techniques to see my server status once upon login.

Comment: Thanks Fossilet, this didn't answer directly to my question, but it's a very interesting way to  obtain the same result or more powerful solution.